# Java - Is what I've written actually a Merge Sort Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

Or is this some close variant?

Fortunately it is pretty fast, I can sort a list of 15,000,000 elements in 20s (of course it depends on local CPU speeds).

I've looked at source code for "actual" merge-sort implementations and none of them remotely look like my code. The algorithm should more or less be the same (I think). It uses a helper method that combines two sorted lists into one combined sorted list. Then the MergeSort method recursively breaks down the unsorted list into halves until it gets to one element sized lists then combines them as it winds up the stack with the helper method stated before.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeSort{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List a = fillListRand(150);
        List sorted = mergeSort(a);
        System.out.println("Done.");
        System.out.println("Unsorted: " + a.toString());
        System.out.println("Sorted:   " + sorted.toString());
     }

     public static List mergeSort(List unsorted) {
        if(unsorted.size() == 1)
            return unsorted;

        return mergeLists(mergeSort(unsorted.subList(0,unsorted.size()/2)),
                          mergeSort(unsorted.subList(unsorted.size()/2,unsorted.size())));
     }

     public static List mergeLists(List a, List b) {
         List newList = new ArrayList();
         int aIndex = 0;
         int bIndex = 0;

         while((aIndex < a.size()) && (bIndex < b.size())) {
            if((int)a.get(aIndex) > (int)b.get(bIndex)) {
                newList.add(b.get(bIndex));
                bIndex++;
            }

            else {
                newList.add(a.get(aIndex));
                aIndex++;
            }
         }

        if(aIndex >= a.size())
            newList.addAll(b.subList(bIndex,b.size()));

        else if (bIndex >= b.size())
            newList.addAll(a.subList(aIndex,a.size()));

        return newList;
     }

     public static List fillListRand(int num) {
         List newList = new ArrayList();
         Random r = new Random();
         for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
             newList.add(r.nextInt(100));
         }
         return newList;
     }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is so different. Also, does this work; is there any reason/gain, as you see it, if you changed it?

Comment: Aside from that, you don't have to check for sizes of the index at the end. You can just `while` dump the remaining elements. The check happens anyway.

Comment: Yes it works really well for my purposes. But I was wondering if I created a deviation/variant of Merge Sort that might not be as Time or Space efficient.

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils The main difference I see in other implementations is the use of left right and middle indexes, it may just be idempotent to the way that I send the unsorted.size()/2 into the arguments of mergeSort()

Comment: Yeah, I assume that's to avoid repeated calls for the size. The `List`, IA, keeps track of the size so it's a simple `return size` type of thing. But at the same time you have to consider the `int`s initializations upon every call as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a merge sort in so far as it divides the elements roughly in half, sorts each half, and merges. The running time is O(n log n), and the extra space usage is O(n). The main difference that you mentioned is that other merge sort implementations often have left, middle, and right indexes. You've just hidden the indexing arithmetic behind calls to `.subList`, which is arguably more elegant, but perhaps less efficient depending on how `.subList` is implemented. If log n repeated calls to `.subList` result in a chain of log n objects, then each element access will cost O(log n) time as it wends its way through the chain. Fortunately, each element is accessed only once in this way, so the asymptotic total running time would be unchanged from O(n log n). (It seems more likely that calling `.subList` on a list constructed with `.subList` would elide the middle object, so that the pointer depth would remain O(1).)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is what I was hoping for.